# How to execute MFC application on any pcs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

I'm trying to release the mfc app which can execute without installing visual studio 2015.
First, When I'm on google, this suggested that I can execute like above by installing vc++ redistributable package.
So I've installed packages but it doesn't work.
And I got the error message. The message is like - "The program cannot start because of missing mfc140ud.dll. ...."

Second, someone said that the release app instead of debug mode can be executed without visual studio.
So I compiled the app on release mode, then I didn't get the error message but it doesn't executed. What's wrong with this?
What can I do?

Comment: ***The program cannot start because of missing mfc140ud.dll*** You are not permitted to run a debug build on a machine that does not have Visual Studio installed. This is against the licence of Visual Studio. This is the reason the redistributable does not have debug dlls.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.
Yeah, you're right.
So can I use release build instead of debug build on a machine that doesn't not have Visual Studio installed?

Comment: Yes of course. Release binaries are permitted without Visual Studio.

Comment: Ok. 
As a matter of fact, I tried release build on a machine you said.
But it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You distributing a DEBUG version of your application.  You can tell that by the name of the DLL it says it can't find.  The "d" suffix of "mfc140ud.dll" indicates it's looking for the DEBUG version of the MFC libraries.  I don't think that the redistributable contains debug version.  Nor should it.

Try releasing a RELEASE build to your clients.

Comment: Thanks, Joe.
Actually, I tried release version, but it doesn't work.
What I say is that the app isn't executed.

Comment: Well that makes it a bit more difficult.  Obviously something is failing without an error message.  At this stage you have a couple of ways to figure it out.  One way is to get a copy of the Windows Dependency Checker, run it on the client machine and load your released app there and see if it tells you any DLLs are missing.  You can get it here:

http://www.dependencywalker.com/

If the problem is missing DLLs, that will tell you right away

Comment: Another approach (assuming it's not a missing DLL) would be to add some temporary logging code to your app.  Right after it starts up (as soon as possible) have your code open up a text file in "C:/temp" or something and write out a line of text.  If you run your release build on the client and you get the file, at least you know that no implicitly loaded DLLs are missing.

Comment: When I open the .exe file with dependencywalker, but the errors appeared.
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
I've just tried to know what exactly these are, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It should tell you which modules are missing.  Look at the tree that it shows you.  You should be able to see the DLLs that are missing easily because they are always highlighted (in red or italic or something like that).    Then you'll have an idea what's missing.

I don't know about the different CPU types.  Check your build settings to make sure all modules are targeting the proper CPU type

Comment: One thing I forgot in posting.
I developed the app on windows 10 x64.
Now, I'm trying to execute the app on windows 7 x64.
I think that here's some issues.
What do you think about this?

Comment: The release version can work on other pcs with windows 10 x64.
Now, I want to execute this app on windows 7 x64.

Comment: At this point I'm really guessing but I would say go into your C++ project settings.  Under "Configuration Properties >> General, look for the "Target Platform".  I'd try to set that to as "old" a version as possible and see if that helps.  I think the "Windows 8.1" setting is as far back as you can go on recent versions of Visual Studio.  Make sure your projects target that and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your application don't run on other PC because is the debug version, compiling to release and distributing on other PC having the visual studio redistributable package will do.

If you want your application to run not depending on the mfc140u.dll you can simply static link your application with MFC. This is easily accomplished going into your project properties.

[image: Project properties, General, Use of MFC]

Your application exe will be bigger but you won't have to bother with these kind of errors anymore. Please note that while this method works on debug too you better not distribute debug code on other machines for a number of reasons.